# getting attributes and values of xml using C#

Tags: c#, xml

i made a program where i retrieve xml code from my database SQL 2005, now i want to display all attribues along with thier values in windows form application. is there any function supports that?? and how?

```
<Permission>
    <CP name="Student">
        <tab name="studentinfo">
        </tab>
        <tab name="notes">
            <groupbox name="ss">
            <field type="textArea" x="xxx" />
            </groupbox>
        </tab>
    </CP>
    <CP name="Teacher">
    </CP>
    <CP name="doctor">
    </CP>
</Permission>
```

output:
name="Student"
name="Student info"

and so on..

Comment: do you have an example schema?

Comment: xml code isnt apearing here but u can get an idea

Comment: there's a code option to show code / xml etc... Its the button with 1010101 on it. I've fixed for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by XML to Linq as bellow:

```
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("a.xml");
        var nodeAttrs = xmlDoc.Descendants().Select(x => x.Attributes());
        foreach (var attrs in nodeAttrs)
        {
            foreach (var attr in attrs)
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Value :{1}", attr.Name ,attr.Value);
        }
```

output is as bellow for your XML:

```
Name: name, Value :Student
Name: name, Value :studentinfo
Name: name, Value :notes
Name: name, Value :ss
Name: type, Value :textArea
Name: x, Value :xxx
Name: name, Value :Teacher
Name: name, Value :doctor
```

**Edit:** And if you have a string which represents your XML you can do

```
    var xmlString = "<Permission> <CP name=\"Student\"> <tab name=\"studentinfo\"></tab><tab name=\"notes\"><groupbox name=\"ss\"><field type=\"textArea\" x=\"xxx\" /></groupbox></tab></CP><CP name=\"Teacher\"></CP><CP name=\"doctor\"></CP></Permission>";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( xmlString );
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream( byteArray);
```

and then

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML to LINQ libraries make this pretty easy

```
  using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("C:/whatever.xml"))
  {
    reader.Read();
    XElement permission = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
    string name = permission.Element("CP").Attribute("name").Value;
    foreach (var tab in permission.Element("CP").Elements("tab"))
    {
      string tabName = tab.Attribute("name").Value;
    }
  }
```

Comment: can u display it in windows form? also i have the xml from database not a seperate file so how can i do it?