# getting xml attributes from SQL

Tags: c#, xml

For this xml (in a SQL 2005 XML column):

```
<doc> 
 <a>1</a> 
 <b ba="1" bb="2" bc="3" /> 
 <c bd="3"/> 
<doc>
```

I'd like to be able to retrieve the names of the attributes (ba, bb, bc, bd) rather than the values inside using C# windows form application.

Comment: Haven't you just asked this one before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237327/getting-attributes-and-values-of-xml-using-c

Comment: yes but that wasn't the exact answer which helps me... i hope i could make it clear now

Comment: Salman your Xml is not in correct format, `</doc>` should be at end, You can skip `attr.Value` in the code that I posted for you, if you fix your current xml issue you will get `ba, bb,bc,bd` also you should remove extra outputs.

Comment: If there is ambiguity in code comment it to explain it

Comment: the first answer in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237327/getting-attributes-and-values-of-xml-using-c shows exactly how to extract the attribute names from your XML.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this - the first method will load the XML string from the database (adjust the connection string and query to your own database, server, table, column names), and the second method will parse the XML string loaded from the database into a list of attribute names based on the answer you got for your previous question:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xmlContent = GrabStringFromDatabase(1);
        List<string> attributeNames = ParseForAttributeNames(xmlContent);

        Console.WriteLine("Your XML attributes are: {0}", string.Join(",", attributeNames.ToArray()));
    }

    private static string GrabStringFromDatabase(int ID)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        string connection = "server=(local);database=test;integrated security=SSPI";
        string query = "SELECT XmlContent FROM dbo.TestXml WHERE ID = @ID";

        using(SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(connection))
        using (SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(query, _con))
        {
            _cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID;

            _con.Open();
            result = _cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            _con.Close();
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static List<string> ParseForAttributeNames(string xmlContent)
    {
        List<string> attributeNames = new List<string>();

        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);

        var nodeAttrs = xmlDoc.Descendants().Select(x => x.Attributes());

        foreach (var attrs in nodeAttrs)
        {
            foreach (var attr in attrs)
            {
                attributeNames.Add(attr.Name.LocalName);
            }
        }

        return attributeNames;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this in your case:

- **If you can create stored procedures on your SQL server:**
  You can create a stored procedure that disassembles the XML into columns, and easily `SELECT` them and have the C# app handle it as if it were a table with columns and rows.
- **If you can't:**
  You can disassemble the XML in C# using `SqlXml` from the `System.Xml` namespace.

Both ways are explained with examples very well here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117(SQL.90).aspx#sql2k5xml_topic4